# Why does Model validation works differently on my local vs on the live server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload, umbraco

I have a website (Umbraco based) with a simple form. This form contains a file upload field.

My model has this property:

```
    [MaxFileSize(5242880, ErrorMessage = "File to big. Max: {0} bytes")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Upload1 { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I have:

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            Log(doLogging, "Invalid Form **************************");
            if (model.Upload1 != null) Log(doLogging, "Attachment1: " + model.Upload1.FileName + ", (" + model.Upload1.ContentLength + ")");
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
```

When I test this on my local machine, I upload a 82kb PDF file, and it works fine.
But when I test this on the live server, my model is invalid with the error:

```
File to big. Max: 5242880 bytes
```

And even more strange, my log file says:

```
WebStart.Controllers.Tp1ContactFormController - Attachment1: Test.pdf, (83617)
```

Where does this weird behaviour come from? It doesn't pass validation, but it can tell the contentsize is 83617 bytes. Why does this work local, but not on a server? Bytes are bytes, right? No regional-settings-problems here I guess.

Comment: **1)** `MaxFileSize` is a custom attribute. So, may be it is necessary to debug code of this attribute on the server. **2)** Check parameters in configuration files (like _web.config_). Might be some way this default value in the code was overwritten by parameters in configuration files on the server. By the way, the `MaxFileSize` attribute usually should be equipped with the `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: I've thought of point 2, but the errormessage uses the given max-size. So that's weird if it uses another value internaly.